# SSIS - Limiting Concurrent Connections

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS to connect to a legecy mainframe database and this allows only 5 concurrent connections at a time.
I have a dataflow task with many tables to transfer and it kicks outs because of this limitation.
I have split up the Data Flow task into seperate data flows and this is working for the moment, but it is not optiomal as they need to be sequenced and 1 large transfer in a flow is holding up subsequent transfers.
Anyone any idea of how to limit the number of connections in a single data flow, I had a look at using the Engine Threads but this did not make any difference.

Any help much appericated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection object you are using for your tasks should have a property named 'RetainSameConnection'. This should cause the same connection to be used across all tasks. At least this is true for OLEDB connection types. I don't know if ADO.NET connections have the same property. They probably do.

Here is an article for more information`:  http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/how-to-retain-same-data-connection-across-multiple-tasks-in-ssis/`

Comment: Thanks Randy, will give that a try and see how I get on. I presume with my situation I can create up-to 5 connections and use them separately.